# How to get the dollar amount of a transaction with different currency used. Paypal REST API

Tags: rest, api, paypal

I have used paypal in my app to process a payment transaction via Paypal REST API and is working fine.

Let say, I made a transaction using EUR as currency and successfully processed the payment.

Is there a functionality wherein I can get the dollar amount of the transaction I've made in different currencies? If there is, would it get the dollar amount based on the exchange rates from the date of the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your primary currency to USD. If so, you can able to receive all the payments in USD. To change the primary currency value Click [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-do-I-change-my-primary-currency-FAQ1030). On every transaction with different currency, paypal will convert the currency to your primary currency value, according to the conversion rate.

Comment: I've already changed my primary currency. How can i get the value converted to USD using the paypal rest API by issuing HTTP get to /v1/payments/sale/sale_id.

Comment: it will be automatically converted to USD, you need to set the currency value as USD in you API call.

Comment: How can I set the currency value in the call to API /v1/payments/sale/sale_id when it only accept 1 parameter (transactionId)?

Comment: "transactions":[
     {
       "amount":{
        "total":"7.47"
        "currency":"USD"
       }
     }
   ]

Comment: you have currency parameter, you need to set that